# JPA: Parameterized instances of AttributeConverter

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, eclipselink

We are developing an application connected to a legacy database. This is very "untyped", using strings for almost all data. What is worse is that is far of being homogeneous: it uses different patterns for dates or times ('YYDDMM', 'HHMMSS', milliseconds) and booleans ('Y'/'N', 'X'/' '), for example.

We want to use JPA (EclipseLink) and custom converters. The problem is that `@Convert` expects a class implementing `AttributeConverter`, so we have to do new classes for each pattern. What I'd like is a BooleanConverter class, which can be instantiated with values 'Y'/'N' or 'X'/' '.

This is obviously out of JPA spec, but maybe it's possible using EclipseLink annotations/configuration. Looking at its [@Convert](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_convert.htm) annotation, a converter can be specified by name. This sounds good to me if I can register a `ynBooleanConverter` and `xSpaceBooleanConverter`:

```
// Unfortunately, this method does not exist :(
Session.addConverter('ynBooleanConverter', new BooleanConverter("Y", "N")); 

@Entity
public class MyEntity {

    @Convert("ynBooleanConverter")
    private Boolean myBoolean;

    ...
}
```

Is it possible? What other options do we have?

Comment: is it suitable for you to use JPA 2.1 converter? available from eclipselink version 2.5 ?

Comment: I can use last version of EclipseLink, but I can't see how to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

Try [@ObjectTypeConverter](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_objecttypeconverter.htm#BGBBDGAI):

```
@Entity
@ObjectTypeConverters({
    @ObjectTypeConverter(name = "ynBooleanConverter", objectType = Boolean.class, dataType = String.class, 
        conversionValues = { 
        @ConversionValue(objectValue = "true", dataValue = "Y"), 
        @ConversionValue(objectValue = "false", dataValue = "N") }),
    @ObjectTypeConverter(name = "xSpaceBooleanConverter", objectType = Boolean.class, dataType = String.class, 
        conversionValues = { 
        @ConversionValue(objectValue = "true", dataValue = "X"), 
        @ConversionValue(objectValue = "false", dataValue = " ") }),
})
public class MyEntity {

    @Convert("ynBooleanConverter")
    private boolean ynBoolean;

    @Convert("xSpaceBooleanConverter")
    private boolean xSpaceBoolean;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works only for Booleans, but not for dates with different formats.

Comment: I guess you have to implement an annotation of your own to achieve that conversion. I doubt that there is support for that logic in either EclipseLink or JPA.

Answer (score 0):

So your Converter behaves different depending on some state in the context? I think I would try to bind the context info to a threadlocal variable which I can read back in the Converter implementation.

Do you have access to a CDI-implementation? Then its even more elegant to inject some bean with your context info into your Converter-implementation. You mentioned that you are missing some `session`-Methods? Maybe a `@SessionScope`'ed bean will help you.

Sadly `@Inject` is not specified in a converter class. You will need to lookup the bean "by hand" like mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29535180/4308751) post.

Comment: Converters don't behave depending on the state, but the actual field which are converting. I have several different patterns for dates saved using strings. I don't want to create so many classes, but only one.

Answer (score 0):

Too late to this thread, but here is a [blog post](https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2018/04/spring-boot-2-generic-jpa-converter-to.html) which shows how JPA converters are to be written. Has working code for String and LocalDate conversions.